# 500 error in web scraping flipkart website

Tags: python, python-requests, data-wrangling

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=smartphones&page=1').text
webpage
```

I can access this flipkart url via web search but when i try to web scrape it through request, I am getting this error. What is the issue? Also, I am a new coder so I apologize if the question is a silly one.

This is the error:
*

## 500 Internal Server Error

An internal server error occurred.

*

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! `500 Internal Server Error` just means there is, well, an error on the web server. It's not necessarily an error in your code. However, this might be an anti-scraping mechanic of the site. Have you tried adding headers such as `User-Agent` to your request?